# How do I remove a vlan from a trunked port

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-commands, trunk

I had a question about a vlan I accidentally added a port to. I have a cisco 2960x 48 port switch. I entered the incorrect port and added it to our wireless vlan. The port is a trunked port to my router in the MDF. I entered the following command

```
sw1(config-if)#switchport access vlan 12
```

now I get the following from

```
sw1#show run inter gi1/0/49

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/49
 description ->MDF-RT01
 switchport access vlan 12
 switchport mode trunk
 logging event spanning-tree
 srr-queue bandwidth share 1 50 30 20
 srr-queue bandwidth shape 5 0 0 0
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
```

I want to remove the vlan 12 from the config without disallowing it across the trunk.

my only idea is to use the command

```
sw1(config-if)#no switchport access vlan 12
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cisco devices you can do the command with `no` in front of it: `no switchport access vlan 12`.

Putting the access VLAN on a trunk port does nothing unless the trunk goes down and the port reverts to an access port.  You have it nailed up as a trunk port.  The access VLAN statement is doing nothing.

Comment: Yep because you haven't specific your trunk allowed list - you are ultimately trunking ALL VLANS - removing access VLAN will not affect this.

Comment: The other option in most versions of IOS besides using the `no` in front is to set it back to the default, in this case it would be `switchport access vlan 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. This was precisely the information I needed.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly an answer, but on IOS you define a vlan as "native" if you want it to go out a trunkport not dot1q tagged.

As the above comments have stated, removing the access statement should be harmless and is good housekeeping.